# Sync. 2 database tables properly

Tags: php

I want to synchronise 2 database tables located in 2 differents servers with a different schema, for example :

Table A fields : id, article_value

Table B fields : article_id, article

Table A is used by one program, table B by an other program.

I want to create a synchronisation script which sync both tables to have the same entries.

I have thought about creating 1 table containing the fields :

A_number (number of articles in table A), B_number (number of articles in table B).

So when the script is launched it counts the number of entries in Table A, and compare with the field A_number. If there is more entries, it adds them in Table B and then update A_number.

Same thing in the other direction.

Is this the best way to do that ? in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add a "last modified" time stamp on both tables? Then you would always know if a row was modified since the last synchronization.

Comment: Yes it is a good solution, but in some tables there is'nt any date, and I can't add the field because I would need to modify both programs.

Comment: You don't have to modify programs - in case the fields you add have default values. Then another programs using the tables would never know there's a new field added. In MySQL, I believe, a common approach is to add a NULLable DATETIME field and have ON INSERT and ON UPDATE triggers setting the DATETIME field to NOW().

Comment: Ah yes I understand. For example I add a trigger ON INSERT to table A and table B who set the date time field to now and then compare in my table 'sync' for example with the date of last synchronisation. (i'm student sorry)

But it needs to add a field in their databases tables ?

Comment: I think you understood it correctly. And yes, if the syncing is two-way, then you have to add such fields to tables in both databases. But then, you'd better also decide which database has more priority, since it may happen that data in BOTH tables has changed since the last sync.